# Run a function while background task is running and return stdout to variable

Tags: bash, shell

I struggled a little defining the correct title. I'm looking for a way to still get a commands result/response I ran, while I use `&` to pass it's pid to another function that shows a loading indicator. This is what I have tried:

```sh
  sizeondisk=$(du -hs "$path" | cut -f1) &
  spinner "" "Getting file size for $path..."
```

So while the command is running it shows a loading indicator and after it has finished it should return the returning value (file size in this case) and pass it into the variable.

Here is the spinning function:

```sh
spinner() {
  local pid=$!
  exitCode=0

  ...spinning here...

  wait $pid &>/dev/null
  exitCode=$?

  return $exitCode
}
```

Comment: If you put an assignment in the background, the assignment only *happens* in that backgrounded, forked-off shell, so your parent shell can't see the resulting variable.

Comment: (Also, I don't know what output you're expecting `wait` to write that you need to redirect; job control messages, f/e, don't actually come from `wait`; instead, they're written by the signal handler routines when a shell is flagged interactive; for a noninteractive shell, like one executing a script, they aren't written at all).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Honestly, the easiest thing to do here is to use a temporary file. There are other approaches, but they're all pretty ugly.

```
tempfile=$(mktemp -t result.XXXXXX)
{ du -hs "$path" | cut -f1; } >"$tempfile" & pid=$!
while kill -0 "$pid" && sleep 1; do
  echo "Spinning..." >&2
done
wait "$pid"; exitCode=$?
sizeondisk=$(<"$tempfile")
```

Comment: This is perfect thanks! I have also submitted my final solution.

Answer (score 0):

While Charles solution is perfect, here is what I have built from it:

```sh
#
# sizeondisk=$(fileSize $path)
#
fileSize() {
  local path="$1"
  tempfile=$(mktemp -qt filesize.XXXXX)
  { du -hs "$path" | cut -f1; } >"$tempfile" &
  spinner "" "Getting file/dir size for $path..."
  sizeondisk=$(<"$tempfile")
  sizeondisk="${sizeondisk// /}"
  echo "$sizeondisk"
  rm -rf "$tempfile"
}
```

Anyone who is interested how the spinner looks like, here it is: https://github.com/muuvmuuv/scripts/blob/master/spinner.sh